# how to update package reference in project c# in vs code not visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to update package reference in project c#  in vs code not visual studio. This is a straight forward process in visual studio but for days now I have been trying to do the same thing in vs code but no success in my finding.

Is there an extension that can do this for .net project? in vs code

I am familiar with the process in visual studio but not in vs code. Since Microsoft is discontinuing VS4Mac soon I'm trying to adjust early.